# How to push items inside an array at the rate at which the screen is being getting captured

Tags: javascript, video, setinterval, mediarecorder, requestanimationframe

I am using **getUserDisplay api** to record the current tab of the user, Now I want to capture the users mouse move positions at the rate it is capturing the screen in (so that each frame could have one object of x and y coordinates)

```js
const constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: true,
  videoConstraints:{
    mandatory:
     {minFrameRate:60,maxFrameRate:90,maxWidth:1920,maxHeight:1080}} 
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserDisplay(constraints)
  .then(stream => {

    const mediaStream = stream; // 30 frames per second
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {
    mimeType: 'video/webm',
    videoBitsPerSecond: 3000000
    });
```

in short > I recorded the screen and send the recorded video to the backend, in the backend decoded the frames, now for each frame there should the mouse x and y coordinates just like doing in real, then I would stich the frames together and form a video
wants to do some editing with the recording

I don't wanna add the cursor on the video in the frontend js, but rather save the mouse coordiates and recorded video seperate and send both to backend

I try using requestAnimationFrame, but its not equal to the number of frames in the video, I tested and number of frames in the recorded video were like 570 and the array only contains 194 items.

```js
 function tests() {
      testf.push('test');
      window.requestAnimationFrame(tests)
    }
```

Thank you so much for reading, any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: So the issue you want us to help you here is the one about the mouse coordinates not being pushed to your Array at the rate you wish, right? The MediaRecorder thing is kind of irrelevant? (If you meant to ask both questions, then do so, but in two separate posts). For that cursor thing, you'd need to show us more of your code. Like when is the interval stopped and the final result logged.

Comment: @Kaiido, pushing the item in the array at the specific rate is just one solution that I try to solve for the problem of not being able to capture at the rate at which the screen is getting captured.
The interval never stopped, its just not pushing the data at the rate of 60 per second, I updated the code for setInterval, the final log is for the length of the array, which should be 600 if its open for 10 second, but its showing the lenght to be 355 approx

Comment: @Kaiido, sorry for the confusion, I edited the original question now :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is technically impossible to capture the mouse position on each recorded frame because API doesn't provide an `onFrame` event or anything similar.

Additionally, because frame rates can technically be different on different devices, I'm not sure it is essential to stick to the recorded frames.

What I would recommend instead is to stick to the timing. What we need to know is that the mouse was at a specific position at the time when the certain frame was recorded. In other words, the mouse and picture on the frame should be in sync.

This can be achieved by starting a timer at the moment when the video recording starts and then using `requestAnimationFrame()` to schedule a function that will record `{ timestamp_msec, mouseX, mouseY, mouseButtons }` where `timestamp_msec` is a time in msec since the moment when video recording started.

We will get a video and an array of the above objects on the receiving side. In the video, you can always obtain the current playing position. Having that position in msec, you can always find the mouse position object, which has a timestamp that is less or equal to the current video position.

Another thing is that `requestAnimationFrame()` gives you a way to precisely match the moment you record the mouse position with the screen update. Even if you record a video with a higher frame rate than `requestAnimationFrame()` can provide, some frames will be just duplicated and have little value.

I've built a few `remote desktop` like systems, and the approach described above works like a charm.

Here is a quick demo with `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
let recordingStart = Date.now(); // set this when you start recording
let lastKnownMousePosition = {};

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  lastKnownMousePosition = {
    mouseX: event.clientX,
    mouseY: event.clientY,
    mouseButtons: event.buttons,
  };
});

const frameHandler = () => {
  const mousePosition = {
    timestamp: Date.now() - recordingStart,
    ...lastKnownMousePosition,
  };
  // send mousePosition to server here
  console.log(mousePosition);
  requestAnimationFrame(frameHandler);
};
requestAnimationFrame(frameHandler);
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Question, I try using websocket messages to send the mouse data to the backend in real time so that there won't be load on the frontend to save all the mouse data and then send it. When I try using websocket connection with requestion animation frame, it was pretty slow as without websocket

Comment: I started a timer and use Mouse Move event to send the mouse position on mouse move with the time.
would you mind showing a small example on the frontend with requestAnimation frame

Comment: @JoelSmith sure, I've added a quick demo. When you say `When I try using websocket connection with requestion animation frame, it was pretty slow as without websocket` what do you mean by `slow`? How much bandwidth your video stream takes? How many mbits connection do you have between FE and BE, and what is your ping time?

Comment: Hey @JoelSmith, was my answer and demo code useful for you? Is there anything else I can help you this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its useful and practical, I am just trying to implement it in my own app, I would definately mark your answer accepted before the bounty expires :)